# regex letters only keypress as event

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, bind, keypress

I wonder what seems to be the problem in here.

```
$("#city_field").bind({
  keypress: function(event){
    var  regex = /^[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜ]/;
    if (regex.test($("#city_field").val())==true) {
    $('.r_validation').html('').css('background-color', '');
    } else {
        $('.validation').html("TEST").css('background-color', 'red');
    }
  }
});
```

Whenever I input letters it is valid, then when I input numbers the red validation notice appears. Everything is fine at this point, not until I entered numbers after letters. The following should be invalid, but in my current script it is seen as valid:

- **foo1212**
- **foo,**
- **foo,** [with space after comma]

What I really want to validate is to ONLY accept letters and dash (-), nothing more other than that.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

For the record, the last comment of  @Adam Rackis solved the issue, I ended up with this working code.

```
$(function(){
  $("#city_field").bind("keyup",
    function(event) {
      var regex = /^[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜ]+$/;
      if (regex.test($("#city_field").val())==true) {
        $('.validation').html('').css('background-color', '');
      } else {
          $('.validation').html("TEST").css('background-color', 'red');
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is matching only one character.  You need to put that input over a Kleene closure, then put an end of string marker:

```
/^[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜ]*$/;
```

Or if you want to make sure there's at least one character, you'd use the positive closure:

```
/^[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜ]+$/;
```

Which produces:

```
var r = /^[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜ]+$/;

console.log(r.test('Foo'));    //true
console.log(r.test('Foo123')); //false
console.log(r.test('foo,'));   //false 
console.log(r.test('foo, '));  //false
console.log(r.test('foo '));   //false
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/653Lu/)

**ALSO**, make sure you catch the `keyup` event, since `keypress` fires *before* the text in your textbox updates, so you're always validating one character behind.

---

So on your Regex:

```
/^[a-zA-ZäöüÄÖÜ]/;
```

When testing `Foo123` the `F` would be consumed, and that's it.  Done.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, however when I use this the string won't validate whenever I input one character only. The validation seems to be fired only upon the input of second character.

Comment: sorry, I commented before even refreshing the browser. Didn't notice your edited answer. The second regex you posted now works on my first comment issue, however when I input in this order: input 1 (invalid), [backspace] input a (still invalid but should change now to valid). Why is that?

Comment: What's the exact string you want to enter.  Your regex will only take letters.  No numbers or backspaces.

Comment: What I mean with **backspace is the action backspace on keyboard. I go in detail with my action: I inputted "1" on the field, the red validation notification appears (which is correct), now I deleted the "1" then replaced with "a", the red notification is still in there. It will be cleared unless I input the second character on the field.

Comment: @D-Lo - you want to catch the keyup event.  Otherwise your regex won't be testing with the most recent textbox value: http://jsfiddle.net/653Lu/3/